JS: getting img and diplaying with callback
I'm following a tutorial to understand AJAX a bit better, i'm not a webdev so i'm not very skillful with JS, but i got my basics down, the example should be able to get an image on screen through way of a callback function, waiting until the client gets the image an displaying it once it's got it.
I know callback is kinda outdated, but since the example uses callback and next exercise is promises it should still work with callbacks, right?
Here's the example code:
function showImage(url, type, callback) {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url)
            xhr.responseType = type;

            xhr.onload = function() {
                callback(xhr.response);
            }

            xhr.send();
}

function createImage() {
            const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
            imageElement.src = objectURL;
            document.body.appendChild(imageElement);
}

showImage('apple.jpg','blob',createImage);

but the image doesn't show.
I fiddled with it for a bit tried some basic stuff like having the url ./apple.jpg and http://localhost/apple.jpg
i tried passing the url as an arg to createImage like so
function createImage(url) {
            const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
            imageElement.src = url;
            document.body.appendChild(imageElement);
}

showImage('apple.jpg','blob',createImage('apple.jpg'));

but there's no way for the img to show on screen, i've checked out if the image is created correctly and on other posts it's pretty much the same using createObjectURL(blob), so i'm assuming it's comething with the callback that's preventing the img from showing, but i honestly don't know.
Any JS expert see what's wrong with this? I'm sure it's super simple and i'm just not seeing it.

The only change you have to make to your code, is add blob as a parameter to your createImage() callback function. The function already tries to use blob, and showImage() already sends the blob to createImage().
function showImage(url, type, callback) {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url)
            xhr.responseType = type;

            xhr.onload = function() {
                callback(xhr.response);
            }

            xhr.send();
}

function createImage(blob) {
            const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
            imageElement.src = objectURL;
            document.body.appendChild(imageElement);
}

showImage('apple.jpg','blob',createImage);


Wow, yes! I'm not clear on where blob is coming from though. Is it the same 'blob' that's passed as an arg to showImage()? Does than mean callback functions have access to the args passed to the function where the callback is being used?

When you call the callback, you pass it xhr.response, which shows up in createImage() as whatever you call the formal parameter. You were trying to use a variable called blob in that function, so you ether needed the formal parameter to be called blob, or you needed to change the variable name you were trying to pass to .createObjectURL() to be the same name as you choose for the formal parameter. If you are not familiar with using functions, you may find more info on mdm: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

You forgot to define blob as an argument:
function createImage(blob) <---



function showImage(url, type, callback) {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url)
            xhr.responseType = type;

            xhr.onload = function() {
                callback(xhr.response);
            }

            xhr.send();
}

function createImage(blob) {
            const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
            imageElement.src = objectURL;
            document.body.appendChild(imageElement);
}

showImage('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353977828-2a4eab540b9a?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8c2FtcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fHww','blob',createImage);




Hi yes, that's totally right and the image does show up when putting blob as an arg. But i'm not clear on where the blob is coming from since i'm not passing anything to createImage() is it coming from the type arg in showImage()? The solution is confusing me more than the problem itself. Thank you!

Cold homey, no need to go first grade level on me. Yeah, i understand i'm passing the http response to the callback function and wasn't declaring the callback function to receive any args. Guess that was a major oversight on my part. Still i was getting confused because of the callback middleman, since i wasn't passing any args when passing the callback function to showImage(). Thank you, i'll be more attentive in the future. I've certainly learned to look how the callback is being called.

When you call the callback, you pass it xhr.response, which shows up in createImage() as whatever you call the formal parameter. You were trying to use a variable called blob in that function, so you ether needed the formal parameter to be called blob, or you needed to change the variable name you were trying to pass to .createObjectURL() to be the same name as you choose for the formal parameter. If you are not familiar with using functions, you may find more info on mdm: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions
